# How to make tappable links in NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make some part of the UITextView Content clickable. Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var definition:UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //self.loadHTML()
    self.makeList()
}

func makeList(){

    definition.delegate = self

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Want to learn iOS? You should visit the best source of free iOS tutorials!")
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com", range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 5))
    definition.attributedText = attributedString
}



func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(URL)
    return true
}
}
```

Some how this is not working. Can you please help what I am missing?

Comment: From the doc of `textView(textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange)`: "Links in text views are interactive only if the text view is selectable but noneditable. That is, if the value of the UITextView selectable property is YES and the isEditable property is NO."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    definition.editable = false;
    definition.delegate = self;
```

Hope can help you.